# Byte buffer exception for strings of length less than 4

Tags: java, string, bytebuffer

I am trying to convert Strings to their integer equivalents for faster comparison using `ByteBuffer` (`java.nio.ByteBuffer`).

I got a very peculiar exception using `ByteBuffer`.

```
public class LargeCompare {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        byte[]b ="zzz".getBytes();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
        bb.getInt();
    }
}
```

The above code does not raise an exception for strings of length 4 but raises one for ones of length 3 and less.

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` is 32 bits, or 4 bytes, wide. You are a trying to read an `int` from a buffer that's shorter than this. This is why you're getting the exception.

I don't really follow where you're going with this, so will refrain from making suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, from the documentation:

> Throws:
>      BufferUnderflowException - If there are fewer than four bytes remaining in this buffer

you only have 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution...

```
public class LargeCompare {

public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "A";
    System.out.println(bytesToInt(str.getBytes()));
}

public static int bytesToInt(byte[] byteArray){          
    int value= 0;
    for(int i=0;i<byteArray.length;i++){                
    int x=(byteArray[i]<0?(int)byteArray[i]+256:(int)byteArray[i])<<(8*i);             
        value+=x;
    }         
    return value;       
}}
```

I have tested this code, working without any issues...